# How to merge two same NSDictionary to NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

There are two dictionaries like this, two dictionaries have same keys but different values.

```
/* dictionary 1 */
paramDict1 {
    payAmount = 1000;
    payType = 1;
}
/* dictionary 2 */
paramDict2 {
    payAmount = 2000;
    payType = 2;
}

I hope merge them to one dictionary like 

paramDict {
    payAmount = 1000;
    payType = 1;
    payAmount = 2000;
    payType = 2;
}

Could you tell me how to do? Thanks.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if NSDictionary preserved the order of keys, which it does not, what you're asking for is impossible because *keys must be unique*.

Instead, you could use an array of dictionaries:

```
NSArray *dicts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: paramDict1, paramDict2, nil];
```

Or perhaps less idiomatically, unique keys:

```
paramDict {
    payAmount1 = 1000;
    payType1 = 1;
    payAmount2 = 2000;
    payType2 = 2;
}
```